Search array of objects with children
There is an array of objects with nested objects. When searching, you need to display all requested results and their parents
const data = [{
  "title": "News",
  "children": [{
    "title": "News1"
  }, {
    "title": "News2",

    "children": [{
      "title": "News22"
    }, {
      "title": "News23"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "title": "Works"
}]

let searchValue = ""
const handleInput = () => {
  return filteredData = data.filter(item => {
    let itemTitle = item.title.toLowerCase();
    return itemTitle.includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
  });
}

example image
example image1
Expected output:
example image3

I don't know why you are getting downvoted this much but I suppose they prefer a textual representation of your expected output instead of images.

You need to recurse to find deeply nested children.

what about children which parent node has a hit?

@Barmar, you never NEED to use recursion. But it is a popular method of doing this :)

@Wimanicesir He needs to go into the nested children somehoiw. There's nothing here that even tries.

You need to filter every level and collect nested values.


const
    filter = (data, string) => data.flatMap(o => {
        if (o.title.toLowerCase().includes(string)) return o;
        const children = filter(o.children || [], string);
        if (children.length) return { ...o, children };
        return [];
    }),
    data = [{ title: "News", children: [{ title: "News1" }, { title: "News2", children: [{ title: "News22" }, { title: "News23" }] }] }, { title: "Works" }],
    result = filter(data, '22');

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }



A slightly different approach by removing empty children.


const
    filter = (data, string) => data.flatMap(({ children = [], ...o }) => {
        children = filter(children, string);
        if (o.title.toLowerCase().includes(string) || children.length) {
            return children.length ? { ...o, children } : o;
        }
        return [];
    }),
    data = [{ title: "News", children: [{ title: "News1" }, { title: "News2", children: [{ title: "News22" }, { title: "News23" }] }] }, { title: "Works" }],
    result = filter(data, '22');

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }



